# insert into select oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i need insert rows on a table that comes of other, the colums in the table are empty but in te base table are full, im using a insert into select but i get: 'Error SQL: ORA-00926'

```
INSERT INTO TABLEROS.V_GRR_EEAF  (PER_ID, EDAD, F_NACIMIENTO, CICLO_VITAL, GENERO_HOM, PERT_ETNICA, DISCAP
        )A  
            (SELECT PER_ID, EDAD, F_NACIMIENTO, CICLO_VITAL, GENERO_HOM, PERT_ETNICA, DISCAP
                FROM FUENTES.V_GRR_EEAF@CONSULTAFUENTES80   B
                    WHERE A.ID_BASE = B.ID_BASE
                     );
```

Comment: insert into t (c1, c2, ...) select ...

Comment: Remove the `A (` in the middle and the final `)` like this: `INSERT INTO TABLEROS.V_GRR_EEAF  (PER_ID, EDAD, F_NACIMIENTO, CICLO_VITAL, GENERO_HOM, PERT_ETNICA, DISCAP ) SELECT PER_ID, EDAD, F_NACIMIENTO, CICLO_VITAL, GENERO_HOM, PERT_ETNICA, DISCAP FROM FUENTES.V_GRR_EEAF@CONSULTAFUENTES80   B WHERE A.ID_BASE = B.ID_BASE;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to update empty columns in A where id_base  exists in B and the updated values should be same as columns in B.

use this statement, it works:

```
MERGE INTO TABLEROS.V_GRR_EEAF a
   USING FUENTES.V_GRR_EEAF@CONSULTAFUENTES80 b
      ON(a.ID_BASE = b.ID_BASE)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
      UPDATE SET 
      a.PER_ID = b.PER_ID, 
      a.EDAD = b.EDAD, 
      a.F_NACIMIENTO = b.F_NACIMIENTO, 
      a.CICLO_VITAL  = b.CICLO_VITAL, 
      a.GENERO_HOM   = b.GENERO_HOM, 
      a.PERT_ETNICA  = b.PERT_ETNICA, 
      a.DISCAP       = b.DISCAP;
commit;
```